Using flutter WebRTC to implement realtime p2p chat feature, but what if one of the peers is offline
I have developed a working chat feature using flutter webRTC between any 2 peers, using a signaling server(firebase). Chat feature works perfectly for realtime communication between 2 peers (when both peers are online), but what if one of the peers get offline, then the data being sent by one peer through the RTCDataChannel will not reach the offline peer, what can i do in this regard? What will be a good approach to accomodate the messages when a peer goes offline?
I am looking for all of the possible approaches to my problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
